# FaceTime says 2 people are active in call

Tags: facetime, call

When calling my sister in FaceTime when she answered the call it said she was active. But then it said she was active again so 2 people by her name in the active FaceTime call but it went to audio only. The call ended up dropping and I called her back and it went back to a normal FaceTime call between her and I. Why did this happen?